# Excel - automatically Save and Exit excel after 5 min

Tags: excel, save

I want to auto-save and close a excel after 5 minutes of inactivity. Is this possible?

If is not than just close excel after 5 min...

I try this

ALT+F11 to open VB editor. Double click 'ThisWorkbook' and paste the first 2 modules in on the right.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 StartTimer
 End Sub
 Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
 StartTimer
 End Sub
```

Now right click 'ThisWorkbook' insert module and paste this code in. Save close and re-open the workbook and after 15 minutes of idle time it will save and close automatically.

```
Const idleTime = 900 'seconds
Dim Start
Sub StartTimer()
Start = Timer
Do While Timer < Start + idleTime
DoEvents
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

but close only workbook and i want to exit excel, and if i use excel still close....

Comment: Yes its possible, what have you tried so far, and whats not working?

Comment: In your `Workbook_SheetChange` you need to stop StartTimer running and start it again, you are trying to run it again but its already running.

Comment: How to stop StartTimer